# Bulk download Sci-Hub papers

Tags: data, open-access, sci-hub

I wonder whether it is possible to bulk download all papers stored in [Sci-Hub](http://sci-hub.bz/).

---

I am aware of the questions:

- [Is there a more user-friendly way to download multiple articles from arXiv?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/55626/452)
- [Bulk download of arXiv (or other publication data set) with metadata AND citations](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/59093/452)

but they focus on arXiv.

Cross-posted question on Open Data (not encouraged by Stack Exchange policy): [Bulk download Sci-Hub papers](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/7084)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the features offered by a particular website.

Comment: @DavidRicherby So how about the two arXiv questions? Why didn't you vote to close them, since they are the same question but for another website?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Because [Sci-Hub](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sci-Hub) is a recent venture of dubious legal status and no original content, while arXiv is a massive, long-standing joint venture that shapes the publication practices of several entire fields.

Comment: @jakebeal Sci-hub is much larger than arXiv in terms of number of papers. Also, Sci-hub is over 4 year-old. As for the legal aspect, it's up to the court to decide, and that shouldn't impact whether the question gets closed anyway.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Thinking that one question should be closed in no way obliges me to check every other question on similar topics.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Sure but I clearly linked them in the question.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt: I think the real issue here is not legality, but rather the fact that arXiv hosts the files, while Sci-Hub merely acts as a proxy to get around paywalls; it can't let you access any interface (in order to, say, enable bulk download) except that which is given by the publishers. Frankly, I very much doubt there is a way to use Sci-Hub to mass-download papers without effectively DDoSing the service, which, ignoring the legal issues, would be simply unethical IMHO.

Comment: This is to say, there are *no* papers "stored in Sci-Hub", as far as I know. Still, I think the downvotes are excessive, so have an upvote.

Comment: @tomasz No paper is a valid answer. I guess I'll just look at it myself without the possibility of sharing the answer here, since the question got closed. They may save PDFs that got queried, I believe some similar services were doing so. E.g. libgen -> https://www.reddit.com/r/Scholar/comments/39dtdf/libgen_mirror/ Also, http://moscow.sci-hub.bz/ccc288e1864c9588274a4de0bd9ff766/10.1002%40%28sici%291097-0347%28199709%2919%3A6%3C545%3A%3Aaid-hed13%3E3.0.co%3B2-4.pdf

Comment: @tomasz As far as I know, libgen is holding a copy of every paper that sci-hub has ever got their hands on.

Comment: Step 1 will be getting your storage ready. An estimate of sci-hub volume was at 40 Tbytes (see comments in https://vk.com/wall-36928352_7448, in Russian).

Comment: Be careful - the last time someone tried to download a massive amount of academic papers from a website it [didn't end well](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aaron_Swartz#JSTOR).

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: Another reason to not obey. Though it wouldn't hurt to be careful.

Comment: Meta question about this question: http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/q/2219/22733

Comment: You need to ask how to download libgen, not sci-hub: that's the library where downloaded papers are stored. Libgen offers to download its database dump (libgen.io/dbdumps/ -- if this link does not work in your country, try typing the address in hideme.ru or similar). I see there two dumps, one is 350 Gb and another 3 Tb, no idea what the difference is. In any case, after you have the dump you can set up your bittorrent client to download the whole library (around 40 Tb with all books and papers). That is how one can set up a mirror of libgen.

Comment: @amoeba sure a valid (and afaik correct) answer is to say no paper are stored on sci-hub but one should download the dump from libgen..

Comment: This is not a useful answer. You can update your question to ask how  to download the dump of libgen. That is the relevant question here.

Comment: @amoeba Why wouldn't it be a useful answer? It sounds to me as giving a solution.

Comment: I don't think it is obvious how to download all papers from libgen. So the answer saying "download all papers from libgen" is only begging the question. Presumably the good answer would contain the specific instructions on how to download all papers from libgen...

Comment: @amoeba understood, sorry I thought you meant the question would indicate how to download all papers from libgen. I agree then it's more a comment.