# Downloading books from websites that allow book upload but promises to remove ones that violate copyright

Tags: copyright

I know of some websites that make it possible for anyone to upload books on their website and then whoever wants to download that book can but the website says they respect copyright and if they found any book that breaks copyright, they will remove it. Some of these websites look into newly-uploaded books to see whether they break copyright or not. Other just allow books to be downloaded but if someone reports that this book is in copyright, they then respond and remove it Others allow upload of books as well and have a message like "if this book is yours and you don't give permission, contact us and we'll remove it" and they do. So I want to know whether downloading books from such websites is legal or not? My main focus is to know whether what these websites do is legal or not, not whether me downloading a pirated book is legal or not. I wanted to search for this but I didn't know what such websites were called.

So in summary:

*Is it illegal if a website allows others to upload books for download but if the author contacts the website or some people report that the author doesn't give permission/the book is copyrighted, they remove the book from being downloadable?

*Is it illegal if a website allows others to upload books for download while regularly checking whether new books are copyrighted and removes them(but before they figure out that this book is copyrighted, downloading is possible)?

*What if the website claims to regularly check books and remove the copyrighted ones but I don't know whether that's true or not, *is it legal to download that book in countries that consider it illegal to hold a pirated book?*
(I'm asking about whether it's legal to download a pirated book for the last question while the other two questions whether what the website did was legal)

Comment: You probably have to show that you genuinely believed the download is legal because the website checked for copyright violations. It will also depend on jurisdiction.

Comment: This is not an academia question; it's one of how copyright law works in general.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does LibGen/SciHub affect researchers' research and publishing process?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/68236/how-does-libgen-scihub-affect-researchers-research-and-publishing-process)

Answer (score 2):

If a work is protected by copyright, that means no one, neither the website nor you, should be making copies without permission.  Making unauthorized copies of copyrighted material is called copyright infringement and it is indeed illegal.

Lots of websites claim they respect copyrights but in many cases, all that means is that if you are the copyright holder and you send them a takedown notice, they'll remove the copyrighted material.  It's possible to sue for copyright infringement but lawsuits are expensive (and may not be practical depending on where the site is hosted) so authors are often satisfied if the material is removed.